# Xbox Destiny Hard Drive Problem

Tags: xbox-360

I bought Destiny the other day for my Xbox 360, and it said I needed an Xbox hard drive, but even when a hard drive was plugged in to the Xbox it still said I needed an Xbox hard drive. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I replaced the tags in your question. Ensure you are tagging the right console. Xbox 360 is the second generation of xbox, so [tag:xbox] directs your question to the wrong people. I also took off the destiny tag, as your not having a problem with destiny, your having a problem with the xbox hard drive. Feel free to re add the tag if i am incorrect, but ensure you can use the hard drive for other games, first.

Comment: If your not able to find a solution quickly on here, [head here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus) with your xbox on, sign in, and opt to speak to a representative over instant messenger. They are often speaking to you within five minutes, and will help considerably to solve the problem. Make sure that if you do solve your problem this way you come back here and tells us what you did to fix it, in a self-answer.

Comment: If your HDD is not above 20GB, you will not have enough space. Let me know if this is the case as Activision do have a solution for this.

Comment: Looks like you have put compatibility packs 1-4 on a USB. They may need to be on the HDD.

Comment: Move the files from the USB to the HDD  and don't have a copy on each.

Comment: What size is your HDD?